# Writing to modbus with Jamod

Tags: java, modbus

I came across with a curious situation when using jamod to write to modbus. Following read code works perfectly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("host.somewhere");
   TCPMasterConnection connection = new TCPMasterConnection(address);
   connection.setPort(502);
   connection.connect();
   ReadMultipleRegistersRequest request = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(0, 1);
   ReadMultipleRegistersResponse response = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse)
       executeTransaction(connection, request);
}

private static ModbusResponse executeTransaction(TCPMasterConnection connection,
         ModbusRequest request) 
         throws ModbusIOException, ModbusSlaveException, ModbusException {
   ModbusTCPTransaction transaction = new ModbusTCPTransaction(connection);
   transaction.setRequest(request);
   transaction.execute();
   return transaction.getResponse();
}
```

But trying to write similar manner fails (Jamod tries 3 times, each times encounters SocketTimeoutException and finally throws ModbusException).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("host.somewhere");
    final TCPMasterConnection connection = new TCPMasterConnection(address);
    connection.setPort(502);
    connection.connect();
    Register reg = new SimpleRegister(0);
    WriteMultipleRegistersRequest request = new WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(0,
        new Register[]{reg});
    executeTransaction(connection, request);
}
```

Yes, I know that I am using multi-register versions of the request-objects, but device I'm working with only supports function codes 3 and 16.

I also wrote raw-socket tester to write registers, and as far as I can see it works correctly. But it would be nice to use jamod in both situations.

Does anyone have anyone experience using jamod and would that one be kind enough to tell what I'm doing wrong? This happens with both 1.1 and 1.2rc1 versions of jamod. Or is this possibly some vendor-specific situation?

Comment: I would first find out if this a jamod or a device problem. Can you try writing to the device with some other means?

Comment: Yes I can. I wrote a tester program that uses tcp-socket to write to the device. At leas in my tests read to socket-written register gives back value recently written to it. (And I used random values, not just zero :)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I wrote my own modbus implementation. I only needed to support 2 different function codes, so implementation was simple.

Although I later found another open source modbus library for java. I someone else comes across the same problem using [modbus4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/modbus4j/) might help.

Comment: I had to do a considerable amount of work on one of the older (it's now 2012 ...) jamod versions to get it to work.  There is a newer version (so if you haven't looked recently, go look again) that may support Modbus/TCP better.

Comment: I eventually threw up my hands in disgust and forked jamod on SourceForge to create "j2mod".  It's the greatly bug-fixed version of jamod I ship with my company's equipment.  The other thing was that jamod doesn't support a large number of Modbus messages, so I implemented every message I could find.  You can find my fork on SourceForge by searching for "j2mod".

Answer (score 2):

Modbus requests have unit id = 0 by default. So any other id must be set to request, e.g.:

```
WriteCoilRequest writeCoilRequest = new WriteCoilRequest(ref, bool);
writeCoilRequest.setUnitID(unitid);
```

Wasted a few hours trying to solve the same problem you described in the question.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I am however unable to test this, but hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

My method which i wrote based on your question works!

```
try {
            ModbusTCPTransaction trans = null; // the transaction

            String refe = "0";// HEX Address
            int ref = Integer.parseInt(refe, 16);// Hex to int
            // int count = 1; // the number Address to read

            ReadMultipleRegistersRequest ainReq = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(
                    ref, count);
            ReadMultipleRegistersResponse ainRes = new ReadMultipleRegistersResponse();

            // 3. Start Transaction
            trans = new ModbusTCPTransaction(con);
            trans.setRetries(5);
            trans.setReconnecting(true);
            trans.setRequest(ainReq);

            int k = 0;
            do {
                trans.execute();
                ainRes = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();
                Register reg = new SimpleRegister(ertekInt);
                WriteMultipleRegistersRequest request = new WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(0,
                        new Register[]{reg});
                System.out.println("Állított AOUT:  " + request.getRegisterValue(k));
                lista.add(createPlanet("AOUT",
                        "" + k + "    " + request.getRegisterValue(k)));
                k++;
            } while (k < count);
} catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I was trying to write a value in a register that was defined in the "device job" as a coil register. So I used:

```
WriteCoilRequest coil_req = new WriteCoilRequest(registerReference,value2write)
```

and that solved the problem. Maybe this help.

Bye!

Comment: Wow, an answer to a 5 year old question. I'm afraid I cant test your solution however, I have not had access to a device in question for years.

Comment: I know that is a little late for the answer but I thought that could be useful for someone else in our same position ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem on Android.

Because this task can take some significant time as it waits for a response from an external device, the solution I found was to execute writing and reading in another thread.